# SQL Server delete rows not in source based on parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, delete-row, sql-delete

I have a table that needs to be updated hourly based on weather forecasts coming in. The create table and merge works great and I have been using them for the last while now.

```
CREATE TABLE #WeatherHourly([Pk_Id][int],
                            [ObservationDateTime] [datetime],    
                            [EffectiveDateTime] [datetime],
                            [Value] [decimal](18, 4)
                           )

MERGE INTO WeatherHourly AS TARGET 
USING #WeatherHourly AS Source ON Target.Pk_Id = Source.Pk_Id 
                               AND Target.EffectiveDateTime = Source.EffectiveDateTime 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET Target.Value = Source.Value,
              Target.ObservationDateTime = Source.ObservationDateTime 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
   INSERT ([Pk_Id], [ObservationDateTime], [EffectiveDateTime], [Value]) 
   VALUES (Source.Pk_Id, Source.ObservationDateTime, Source.EffectiveDateTime, Source.Value);
```

But what I've noticed is that sometimes new forecasts don't include old data that I have already written to the table. This means that some data is sticking around because nothing ever writes over/updates it in the merge statement. This data is really not valid anymore since it's not included in the newest forecast. Now just adding a 'not matched by source' in the merge would work, though it would delete all rows of history. I am keeping the history currently for other reasons and can not delete old rows,but only rows that are in WeatherHourly table and still relevant/(EffectiveDateTime within range from yesterday to any future date). The code below is what I've tried so far but it would delete all the history rows I don't want deleted.

```
Delete from WeatherHourly from WeatherHourly tRow 
left JOIN #WeatherHourly t2 ON tRow.EffectiveDateTime = t2.EffectiveDateTime and   tRow.Pk_Id = t2.Pk_Id
where t2.PK_Id is null
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit for my new approach:
I'm wondering about using a better select for my original merge to make the target more what I would like.

```
WITH    t2
AS
(
SELECT  *
FROM    WeatherHourly t
WHERE   EXISTS
(
SELECT * FROM #WeatherHourly r WHERE t.EffectiveDateTime = r.EffectiveDateTime AND  t.Pk_Id = r.Pk_Id
)
)
MERGE t2
AS Target
USING   #WeatherHourly
AS Source
ON Target.Pk_Id = Source.Pk_Id 
    AND Target.EffectiveDateTime = Source.EffectiveDateTime 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET Target.Value = Source.Value,Target.ObservationDateTime = Source.ObservationDateTime 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT ([Pk_Id],[ObservationDateTime],[EffectiveDateTime],[Value]) 
    VALUES (SourcePk_Id,Source.ObservationDateTime,Source.EffectiveDateTime,Source.Value)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN 
    DELETE;
```

This seems to be doing what I wanted. Any critique would be helpful. Sorry to whomever is going to fix this code mess up.

Comment: Please consider the NOT EXISTS pattern. MERGE can be problematic as there are over a dozen unresolved bugs (never mind that the syntax is really cumbersome to write and comprehend, and doesn't buy you the concurrency control you might expect - unless you add aggressive hints), and the LEFT JOIN approach is notoriously slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH    t2
AS
(
SELECT  * FROM WeatherHourly t
WHERE EXISTS
(
SELECT * FROM #WeatherHourly r WHERE t.EffectiveDateTime = r.EffectiveDateTime AND t.Pk_Id = r.Pk_Id
)
)
MERGE t2
AS Target
USING   #WeatherHourly
AS Source
ON Target.Pk_Id = Source.Pk_Id 
    AND Target.EffectiveDateTime = Source.EffectiveDateTime 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET Target.Value = Source.Value,Target.ObservationDateTime = Source.ObservationDateTime 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT ([Pk_Id],[ObservationDateTime],[EffectiveDateTime],[Value]) 
    VALUES (SourcePk_Id,Source.ObservationDateTime,Source.EffectiveDateTime,Source.Value)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN 
    DELETE;
```

After testing this seems to work well.

Answer (score 0):

Why not delete pre-existing for EffectiveDateTime, and then inserting new?

```
DELETE FROM WeatherHourly
WHERE  EffectiveDateTime = ( SELECT TOP(1)
                                  EffectiveDateTime
                              FROM
                                  #WeatherHourly )


INSERT INTO WeatherHourly
(
    [Pk_Id]
    ,[ObservationDateTime]
    ,[EffectiveDateTime]
    ,[Value]
)
SELECT
    [Pk_Id]
    ,[ObservationDateTime]
    ,[EffectiveDateTime]
    ,[Value]
FROM
    #WeatherHourly
```

Comment: Why would you add NOLOCK here? Please don't be one of those folks that puts NOLOCK on every single SELECT. This can be really, really bad news.

Comment: It's required where I work, and didn't know better.  Removed from my answer.

Comment: Hope you don't work at a bank (or anywhere where accuracy is even close to important).

Comment: I'm not sure if this would work, and I can't completely remember why I went the merge route. It was a while ago. When I merge I am doing across several different Pk_Id and multiple EffectiveDateTime for each, all with the same ObservationDateTime. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: What is the `TOP` without `ORDER BY` supposed to do? Select a random row from `#WeatherHourly` and delete the related row from `WeatherHourly`?